# Letting user choose a directory to save a file, if directory doesn't exist how to ask for a directory again

Tags: python, file, file-io

I'm writing a script to save a file and giving the option of where to save this file. Now if the directory entered does **NOT** exist, it breaks the code and prints the Traceback that the directory does not exist. Instead of breaking the code I'd love to have have a solution to tell the user the directory they chose does not exist and ask again where to save the file. I do not want to have this script make a new directory. Here is my code:

```
myDir = input('Where do you want to write the file?')
myPath = os.path.join(myDir, 'foobar.txt')
try:
    f = open(myPath, 'w')
except not os.path.exists(myDir):
    print ('That directory or file does not exist, please try again.')
    myPath = os.path.join(myDir, 'foobar.txt')
f.seek(0)
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: Are you familiar with loops? The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-while_stmt) can help.

Comment: start with placing `os.path.exists(...)` in an `if` statement to check before trying to use the path.

Comment: You code is not even functional...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you started however I will note that I think you need to tweak the input statement so the user does not have to put quotes in to not get an invalid syntax error

```
import os
myDir = input("Where do you want to write the file ")

while not os.path.exists(myDir):
    print 'invalid path'
    myDir = input("Where do you want to write the file ")
else:
    print 'hello'
```

I do not know what your programming background is - mine was SAS before I found Python and some of the constructions are just hard to think through because the approach in Python is so much simpler without having a goto or similar statement but I am still trying to add a goto approach and then someone reminds me about how the while and while not are simpler, easier to read etc.

Good luck

I should add that you really don't need the else statement I put it there to test/verify that my code would work.  If you expect to do something like this often then you should put it in a function

```
def verify_path(some_path_string):
    while not os.path.exists(some_path_string):
        print 'some warning message'
        some_path_string = input('Prompt to get path')
    return some_path_string



if _name_ == main:
some_path_string = input("Prompt to get path")
some_path_string = verify_path(some_path_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, definitely puts me on the right track. I actually have been programming for a few years, self taught with Python/Django...a great deal of my few years has been working with Django. But now I find myself in a core python team and learning the ropes. Thank you for this help!